# React/NextJS - How do I show results of an array

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following code which conditionally renders output based on if there is an event in my room booking system. Why can't I get it to show the list of names that comes from `const namesList ....`?

```
import { getEventsTodayByLocation, getEventCustomData } from "./layout"

export default async function Page({ params: { location } }) {

    const eventsTodayData = getEventsTodayByLocation(location)
    const event_CustomData = getEventCustomData(location)

    // Wait for the promises to resolve
    const [ eventsToday, eventCustomData ] = await Promise.all([ eventsTodayData, event_CustomData ])

     // Get the names and production details
        // Step 1: .map() through and .filter() the 'groups' to show just the information required for the screen
        const namesList = eventCustomData.data.map(( { groups }) => {
            const tab_name = groups.filter(group => group.keyword === 'drscreens')

            // Step 2: .map() through the results - originally called 'children' in the Array but reassigned to 'details_and_names'
            tab_name.map(( { children: details_and_names }) => {

                // Step 3: Create two Arrays from the results called 'prod_details' and 'name_details'
                const [ prod_details, names_list ] = details_and_names

                // Step 4: .map() through 'names_list' to get each name from the Array
                names_list.children.map((names) => {
                    console.log(names.value)
                    return (
                        <p>{names.value}</p>
                    )
                })  
            }) 
        })

    if ( eventsToday.data.length === 0 ) {
        
        return (
            <p>Room Available</p>
        )

    } else {

        return (
            <p>{namesList}</p>
        )
    }

}
```

The code works - the `console.log(names.value)` gives me the names I am expecting I just can't get beyond that point.

Have tried various options and gave up. The `<p>` tags in the return show up in my rendered page but as `<p></p>`

I suspect it is going to be annoyingly simple to solve.

Comment: You are never returning anything in your first "layer" of mapping. In third map the return changes content of `names_list.children`, it's not returned to `namesList`